# cant have project structure "src/main/java" in eclipse using Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I used to have a "src/main/java" gradle project structure in eclipse, but after some changes by another person and subsequent pulls from github I lost that project structure and it is now a total mess. Also gradle is not loading any dependency and says "the import ..cannot be resolved"!

How to take control of that?

In the pic I show two diff projects, in the left one with a correct folder structure "src/main/java", in the right the one with issues...[pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkDAw.png)

I already tried changes in the build path and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That is a setting of eclipse of which folder is considered a source code folder. You can change that in the project's settings.

Comment: "i already tried changes in the build path and it dosnt seems to work." *What changes?* Did they include removing the existing Source Folder entry and adding `src/main/java` in its place?

Answer (score 0):

had the other person updated any information with `build.gradle` ?

```
sourceSets {
    main { 
        java { srcDirs = ["src/main/java"] }
        resources { srcDir "src/main/resources" }
    }
}
```

I believe this should fix the issue for you , or if you can share your `build.gradle` file then We can have a look .

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i fixed the project structure as suggested by @f1sh  in the build path-> Source , i removed the incorrect "Source folders on build path" and added the correct path "src/main/java"......but still have the issue importing the depenedencies with gradle, im using STS and gradle works well with other projects, what could be wrong?   this is my build.gradle

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/9vbdKmLJ

Comment: The links seems to be empty , if you can upload again . Am familiar with STS hope i can help .